# How to add pause between requests?

Tags: paw-app

I have a set of requests I run together in a group.  One of them starts some async operations on the server.  I need to insert a n-second pause between this request and the next to give those async operations time to complete.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it isn't possible yet with Paw. Though we're going to bring a nice testing flow (with assertions, request flow, waits, etc.) in a future release.

As a temporary workaround, you could add a dummy request to a "sleep" page alike: http://httpbin.org/delay/3

A screenshot to explain this better (and a [video here to see it run](http://cl.ly/3V3W191B2C0s)):

[image: Dummy sleep request with Paw]

Comment: Haha, I actually mocked up something similar: making multiple requests to a longish-loading (~2 sec.) page. But thank you for http://httpbin.org/delay/n-seconds.

Comment: Yep, sorry, we don't have a better solution for now – but that's just for now – we will be working on it :)

Comment: @MichaMazaheri over two years later and it doesn't look like Paw 3.1.7 has this feature in it.